# How to add htmlContent UI Component in product_form.xml custom attribute product group?

Tags: magento2, layout, product-attribute, uicomponent, attribute-group

I create a custom product attribute with a custom group like this:

```
     $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'trademark',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Trademark',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'backend' => '',
            'sort_order' => '75',
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'default' => 'No Trademark',
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'unique' => false,
            'group' => 'General',
            'used_in_product_listing' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'option' => array('values' => array("")),
            'group' => 'Meridian'
        ]
    );
```

I apply a custom group fieldset named Meridian to this custom attribute product.
I tried to add a custom htmlContent UI component to this custom group, by extending **product_form.xml** in a custom extension like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
     <fieldset name="Meridian"> 
        <htmlContent name="meridian_extended">
            <block name="space-input" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\MeridianLocator">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::catalog/product/edit/meridian-locator.phtml</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </htmlContent> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I tried to put the Group name in the fieldset, but when i open the edit product page, the page always becomes blank, when i remove the fieldset the page is there and the html content appears, but it appears at the bottom of the page. I want this htmlContent inside the custom product attribute group, how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify product edit form you need to follow another one logic

**1. Define custom Product Form modifier**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="acme_product_meridian_locator" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Acme\StackExchange\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\MeridianLocator</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

**2. Create modifier and modify metadata/data**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/MeridianLocator.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessorInterface;

class MeridianLocator extends AbstractModifier
{
    public const ATTRIBUTE = 'trademark';

    protected LocatorInterface          $locator;
    protected PropertyAccessorInterface $propertyAccessor;

    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        ?PropertyAccessorInterface $propertyAccessor = null
    ) {
        $this->locator          = $locator;
        $this->propertyAccessor = $propertyAccessor
            ?: PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        // example of update product form data if needed
        $product = $this->locator->getProduct();
        if ($product->getId()) {
            $data[$product->getId()]['product'][self::ATTRIBUTE] = '';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $group = null;
        foreach ($meta as $groupCode => $groupData) {
            if (!isset($groupData['children']) || !is_array($groupData['children'])) {
                continue;
            }
            foreach ($groupData['children'] as $fieldCode => $fieldData) {
                if ($fieldCode === 'container_' . self::ATTRIBUTE) {
                    $group = $groupCode;
                    break 2;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!$group) {
            return $meta;
        }

        // example to update attribute config
        try {
            $configPath = '[' . $group . '][children][container_notes][children]['.self::ATTRIBUTE.'][arguments][data][config]';
            $config     = $this->propertyAccessor->getValue($meta, $configPath);
            // update config
            $config['template'] = '...';
            $this->propertyAccessor->setValue($meta, $configPath, $config);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {}

        return $meta;
    }
}
```